# why the local .js file size is not the same as browser request back from server?

Tags: javascript, web, server

I used react and webpack to build up a `.js` file like below.

> 5.9M ./app.8d30cc2e71548cd03a7b.js

but when it is uploaded to the server and then visit from browser. The network display like this.

[image]

the same file, why the size change a lot, amazing.

what happened in this process?

Comment: If your browser supports compression, it might be downloading web pages compressed with gzip.

Comment: The server may be using compression, such as gzip. Click on the file and view the servers response headers

Comment: @samdd `content-encoding:gzip`  aha!  is the server always use this tech for the file? or we have to config?(I am a junior front-end)